# Galaxybase client prompt:"Connect reset by peer."

Tags: graph-databases

My Galaxybase client shows: "Connect reset by peer.” I thought I might have internet fluctuations here, so I checked it but everything is fine. Restarting the service didn’t help. After 3 hours I tried again and still had the same situation. What else could possibly be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection has been abruptly terminated. The reason of encountering this problem could be:

1. The server/client was closed unexpectedly, causing the connection to be closed incorrectly.
2. There may be network fluctuations or timeout strategies between the client and server, causing the connection to be interrupted.

The underlying reason is that, the connection receives the RST packet of TCP.

You can try to solve it according to the following steps

1. Make sure if the server is shut down abnormally or unavailable, check your firewall.
2. Identify network policies and fluctuations.
3. Try to send the request again.